# Linear regression - Simulation - "what if" scenario

Tags: r, regression, self-study, multiple-regression

I have an assignment at university and  I have been given a simple situation which I would like to explain here.

**Situation:**
I would like to perform  simulation on **purchase price** of a product and see the impact of this change on **sales price** and **quantities sold** of a product.

As long as **purchase price** varies, the sales price also varies. If sales price of product increases, people buy fewer goods hence quantities sold varies and vice versa. So,

1) Sales price of a product depends on the purchase price.

2) Quantities sold depends on sales price.

For this, I thought of using simple linear regression to build two models keeping **purchase price** as independent variable and changing the two dependent variables each time. Later combine the two models to predict the future values for every new purchase value.

Kindly share your thoughts if you believe it could be done with a better solution.

Thanks.

**NOTE** : To anyone referring to this question: I am just looking for ideas on my approach. Based on that I will come up with a solution on my own. Any thoughts fruitful/not fruitful doesn't matter. It will help me broadening my knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Given that this is for an assignment please add the [self-study] tag and read it's wiki because we treat such questions a little differently. Thanks!

Comment: Still looking forward for your thoughts  :) Thanks